# How to use AuthenticationMiddleware and inject application settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried following this example: https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/no-configurationmanager-in-aspnet-core-GC

with no luck.

It compiles but, my setting don't come back. The link says the json file should be in the Configuration folder.

Is there another way to do this?

Just trying to have my connection string in a settings file some how.

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}

public class Settings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}


    public class Startup
    {
        private Settings _settings;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();//.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // Added - uses IOptions<T> for your settings.
            services.AddOptions();

            // Added - Confirms that we have a home for our DemoSettings
            services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware<IOptions<Settings>>>();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

And the middleware

```
public class AuthenticationMiddleware<TOptions>
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private Settings _settings;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="settings"></param>
    /// <param name="next"></param>
    public AuthenticationMiddleware(IOptions<Settings> settings, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
        {
            //Extract credentials
            string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));

            int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

            var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
            var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

            if (username == "test" && password == "test")
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // no authorization header
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the defination for `AuthenticationMiddleware`?

Comment: I'll add AuthenticationMiddleware tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

For using `Settings` in `AuthenticationMiddleware`, you could try below:

1. Add section below to `appsettings.json`

   ```
   {
     "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
         }
      },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "Settings": {
     "ConnectionString": "Data Source=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create `AuthenticationMiddleware`

   ```
   public class AuthenticationMiddleware
   {
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
   private readonly Settings _settings;
   public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<Settings> options)
   {
       _next = next;
       _settings = options.Value;
   }

   public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   {
       //await context.Response.WriteAsync($"This is { GetType().Name }");
       //decide whether to invoke line below based on your business logic
       await _next(context);
   }

   }
   ```
3. Register `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `Settings`

   ```
    //Configure Settings
    services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));

    //Configure middleware
       app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
   ```

Comment: I did all that. See above

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was where the json file was. Nothing explicitly stated where it should be. The root of the project.

Comment: And Microsoft's crappy design doesn't state where it's look, just returns null. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: By default, `appsettings.json` is in the project root. You could check [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more information about `Configuration`